# How to set order of appearance for fields when using Html.EditorFor in MVC 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, editorfor

I have the following classes in my Model:

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required,StringLength(500)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Model : SortableEntity
{
    [Required]
    public ModelType Type { get; set; }
    [ListRequired]
    public List<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
    public List<PrintArea> PrintAreas { get; set; }
    public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

To display the "Model" class in the view I simply call Html.EditorFor(model=>model), but the "Name" property of the base class is rendered last, which is not the desired behaviour.

Is it possible to influenece on the order of displayed fields somehow?

Comment: There is a decent solution here http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/11/Ordering-fields-in-ASPNET-MVC-2-templated-helpers.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to find an attribute for that, so your options are:

1) create one, and then revise the base Object.ascx template to account for it, or
2) create a custom editor template for your classes that explicitly put stuff in the order you want.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Ended up discarding base classes (Entity, SortableEntity etc.), creating interfaces (IEntity, ISortableEntity) and added correspoding properties manually in all the classes.